# Cannot find selenium package even if it is defined in pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Here is the pom.xml file that I am using :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>shiv</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ab</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <webdriver.version>2.53.0</webdriver.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <ghostdriver.version>1.1.0</ghostdriver.version>
    <phantomjs-maven-plugin.version>0.7</phantomjs-maven-plugin.version>
    <phantomjs.version>2.1.1</phantomjs.version>

</properties>


<dependencies>

    <!-- Junit 4.11 needs hamcrest 1.3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>${webdriver.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

As you can see I am already getting the latest selenium version 2.5.3, still it gives out following error:

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :

[ERROR] /Users/sp/xyz/src/main/java/webdriver/manager/Driver.java:[6,1] package org.openqa.selenium does not exist

[ERROR] /Users/sp/xyz/src/main/java/webdriver/manager/Driver.java:[11,36] package org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit does not exist

Is there something that I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see **htmlunit-driver** dependency in you pom.xml. Starting with **2.53.0** you need to explicitly include HtmlUnitDriver as a dependency to include it.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
```

See [this](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp) for more details.

Comment: So, I added the above change and it worked, but still it is complaining that the package   "org.openqa.selenium" does not exist.

Comment: Try using <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Ok, found the problem..for some reason it was not added to my class path..Thanks for your help though..appreciate it..